# How do major 7th chords (no inversion) sound consonant?

Tags: guitar, chord-theory

A note and its flat or sharp do not sound good played together.  The sound is as dissonant as it gets.

How is it that placing a 3rd and 5th between a note and its major 7th (flat of its octave), then playing the four notes as a chord, makes a consonant sound?  Is there some mix of frequencies that makes the dissonance blend into consonance?

On the contrary, play the major 7th note as the lowest note of a chord, at least on guitar, and it sounds terrible. Example: C E G B sounds nice, pretty, airy, even though C and B are being played together. Play B C E G and is sounds so dissonant (sour/off) a listener would think a mistake has been made.

How does putting the E and G between C and B quell the dissonance to the point a very pretty chord is played, and why are E and G no help if the chord is inverted with B as the lowest note? (On guitar at least) Please note: I know only elementary math. Math algorithms, equations, etc. have no meaning for me.

Comment: In classical harmonic theory, a major seventh chord is not consonant.

Answer (score 6):

It's pretty straightforward; it's a matter of "distancing and diluting" the dissonance.

This is "very dissonant"*:

[image]

... and this is "less dissonant":

[image]

The "clash" of the two notes has been reduced by distance. (Disclaimer: the explanation that follows may be inaccurate; the math confuses me.) Insofar as there is any objective math to "dissonance,"** that's because the first example has "beats" that are less frequent and therefore more noticeable. That is, when the two sound waves play at the same time, some times they "add up" to a louder moment and sometimes they cancel each other out. If we had this:

[image]

... then for each wave of the bottom C, exactly two waves for the top C would fit into it, and they'd line up nicely and sound "smooth." Or, if we had this:

[image]

... then both waveforms would be identical***; their peaks and valleys would line up, and we'd hear one pitch. But if we de-tune one C just slightly, then its wave would become longer; they'd start in sync, but every so often, after X milliseconds, it would wind up in a valley while the other one is in a peak, and they'd cancel out. And after another X milliseconds they'd be back in sync and reinforce each other again. At intervals smaller than a half step, the X unit of time can take so long that you can hear each individual "beat" and it can be quite noticeable. As the pitches diverge and the beats speed up, at some point we describe it as sounding "rough."

So anyway, the major 7th fits in twice as many Bs into each C, so the beats are more frequent, less additive, and less noticeable.

*Meanwhile*, making a seventh chord out of the whole thing:

[image]

... "dilutes" the dissonance because there are a bunch of consonances present as well. We could see this basically as a C major triad plus an e minor triad, superimposed. For modern sensibilities, both major and minor thirds are consonant, and we've got three of them! In subjective terms, the clash is "softened" by all these "nice intervals." (In some ways, this major seventh chord is even better than the dominant seventh because we lack the dissonant tritone we'd find between E and B flat.) In more objective terms as well, the other pitches add their interference patterns, and any beats between the C and B get softened by the interaction of all the other notes.

---

* But "as dissonant as it gets"? That's tricky, and depends on context and subjectivity. Plus, of course, if we step outside the equal-tempered 12-tone scale, for instance, two pitches separated by a quarter step will clash much more than a half step.

** There isn't always. "Dissonant" is a subjective and cultural word, and is also influenced by factors other than pitch anyway.

*** Theoretically, and especially if artificially generated. Things like instruments, human imprecision, speakers, and sound moving from the speakers through a room to our ears could make them not truly identical.

Comment: I often wonder whether the actual instrument, with its peculiar, unique  overtone system, has a bearing on the question.

Comment: @Tim the overtone spectrum doesn't really impact this, since humans strongly tend to perceive only the spectrum's _fundamental_ as the pitch. Even when the fundamental frequency is removed from the spectrum, we still hear it as the pitch (residual pitch phenomenon). So which consonances/dissonances are formed by the overlapping spectra of different notes does not matter to our perception, we just hear the consonances and dissonances formed by the fundamentals

Comment: I get the distancing the dissonance concept but still wonder how this is possible.  I am wondering what physically is going on with the sound waves that sweetens up the dissonance of two notes by adding one or two more notes (forming a maj 7) to a chord.  I can easily demonstrate the phenomenon on guitar but cannot explain what is happening and wish I could in the most practical language possible.

Comment: @ejbpesca The math of wave interference confuses me too, but maybe some visual illustrations of it will help. I don't have time to draw right now, but maybe this page, although it's not a complete explanation, will help: https://www.physicsclassroom.com/class/sound/Lesson-3/Interference-and-Beats (or also http://ffden-2.phys.uaf.edu/webproj/211_fall_2020/Jared_Bowden/Jared_Bowden/harmony_page_3.html )

Comment: @ejbpesca Your comment makes the assumption that something *is* "physically is going on with the sound waves".  More likely it's something "going on" in our auditory system (ears and brains).

Comment: Yes, something is going on with perception of sound.  I would like to know the physics of the musical sound wave(s) that causes that perception.  How simply can I put this.  Here is the sound of two discordant notes, I add two more notes and those two notes that sounded "off," together now sound smooth together.  Perhaps a graphic of frequencies blending could show it or some (simple as possible) explanation of how one sound can cancel another is the answer. I demonstrate the phenomenon for learners, I want to be able to explain how it happens.  Maybe it is unknown.

Comment: Andy Bonner thanks.  That page is over my head but it maybe affirms my theory that the other two frequencies added (notes) somehow over power the two notes that have so much dissonance, like forcing them into consonance.  Maybe something similar to physics of noise cancellation?  The answer may be too scientifically involved for me to understand.

Comment: @ejbpesca It's both physical *and* perceptual. I mean, my answer above is all about waves physically interacting; that does happen. Meanwhile, you can play a C into one ear of headphones and a B into the other; the hearer will perceive dissonance but no waves are actually "touching." That's its own big topic that I don't know much about. Meanwhile, I think whether physically *or* perceptually, it's as simple as "adding two consonances to a dissonance makes the whole thing 'more consonant.'" The B clashes with the C, but not with the E or G. The "net dissonance" is less.

Comment: @ejbpesca Remember, this is only partly objective. Medieval theorists considered a third to be a dissonance. So, as long as we consider it a consonance, our cultural perception of dissonance is being assuaged by them. Meanwhile, on the objective front, you have everything I said above about the additional waveforms "interfering with the interference" pattern that the B and C alone created.

Comment: I have terrible tinnitus.  I run box fans to make it almost disappear from my auditory perception of my home sound environment.  Maybe that is something like what happens with a maj 7 chord.  I also have experience deep bass notes covering over other frequencies when I mix sound for local bands.  It seems not just volume, but an ability of low frequencies to destroy the receiving of higher ones. (Bass can ruin the sound of a rock band)  I will try playing E and G notes with less and less volume to see if the dissonance rises between the C and B and other experiments.

Comment: This phenomena probably can be shown with 2D representations of frequency waves blending, but for me to understand what happens with them as they blend, it would have to be shown, if possible, in a very elementary fashion.

Comment: @ejbpesca Yeah, again a mix of physics and psychoacoustics. White noise helping tinnitus = neurological, but meanwhile you're quite right that low frequency pitches can interfere a lot with higher pitches (physically). With a broader amplitude, they have more power. Meanwhile, as others have suggested, if you want a very "pure" way of examining these pitch relationships, perhaps try an instrument other than guitar, like synths, especially a sine wave.

Answer (score 4):

It’s safe to say there is both objectivity and subjectivity when discussing dissonance and consonance. I do agree with your statement that a major 7th chord sounds much more consonant than just a M7 interval. I believe the reason for this is actually very simple. In its most basic form a major 7th chord is a pair of perfect 5ths, for example, Cmaj7, you have C-G and E-B. The M3 and m3 intervals contained within are also consonant. Even if you re-voice a maj7 chord it will usually yield intervals (4ths, 6ths, etc) that are more consonant and take the “sting” out of the M7 interval in the chord.

As for your comment about the Cmaj7 with the B below the C “at least on guitar”, this particular voicing is not guitar friendly at all unless some type of alternate tuning is used and is pretty much impossible for chords where you can not incorporate at least one open string. The only way I could think of to play that voicing is this: X-15-14-12-0-X. Regardless of that, it may sound bad to you but some people do like voicings that have clusters in them so I would say your statement is a bit subjective on this point.

The one thing you do want to avoid in terms of voicings and dissonances is placing the M7 a m9 below the root, that’s definitely a chalkboard scratcher!

Comment: "The one thing you do want to avoid in terms of voicings and dissonances is placing the M7 a m9 below the root": unless it resolves or is a passing dissonance.

Comment: @phoog I’ll buy that. I was thinking in terms of a static voicing for my answer.